# Issue with Kivy app window not launching in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy, kivy-language

Iv been trying to run the basic "Hello World" Kivy app in Pycharm but cannot seem to get it to work. Iv read through other post from others with similar issues but still haven't been able to solve the problem.

**My code**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyFirstKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Label with text Hello World is
        # returned as root widget
        return Label(text="Hello World !")

MyFirstKivyApp().run()
```

**ERROR**

My issues is I get this error when the app is ran

```
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Jimmy\PycharmProjects\Swipe\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 16:30:00) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Jimmy\PycharmProjects\Swipe\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
File "C:\Users\Jimmy\PycharmProjects\Swipe\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
 fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1086, in __import__
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\Jimmy\PycharmProjects\Swipe\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 28, in <module>
 from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort
```

Iv tried deleting and reinstalling Kivy and updating all the files refenced in the documentation. Also I have no issue running the import files.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
```

It just seems like Pycharm is struggling to run the apps vm. Lol I had ChatGPT review the error code and it seems to think there is an issue with the installation so Iv tried deleting and reinstalling with no luck. Below is a snapshot of all the packages I'm using.

Iv seen some post talking about adding in a *kivy_venv* directory but not sure if that's in Pycharm or inside apps folder.

[image]